# How to persist HttpContext.Current between projects in same solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, httpcontext, formsauthentication

I'm new to the concepts of FormsAuthentication and am struggling with something.

I have an MVC4 project, MyApp.Web, which has an AccountController with a Login method:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    string siteName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteName"];

    if (ModelState.IsValid && MembershipService.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, siteName))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Main", "Home");
    }
}
```

MembershipService is in another project (Class Library)

```
public bool Login(string username, string password, string site)
{

    // ....
    // do the validation, set up my ClaimsPrincipal and create a FormsAuthenticationTicket,
    // which is stored in the Cookies collection

    // now, we can save the ClaimsPrincipal to the relevant place
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal;
    else if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null)
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;   

    return success;
}
```

That all seems to work perfectly, I am validated as necessary, the ClaimsPrincipal is created and stored.

My issue is, when I am redirected, back in MyApp.Web, to HomeController and I put a breakpoint in the Main method, HttpContext.Current is not the same as the one I had in my Membership project; none of the values that I set up in the Login method have persisted.

So, simply, how do I ensure that they are the same and setting values on HttpContext.Current in one project carry through to any other projects I may have in the same solution?

Thanks